# Is there a way to load .RData or .model files in sparkR (using databricks)?

Tags: r, apache-spark, databricks, sparkr, rdata

I'm using sparkR inside databricks environment and I'm trying to load an XGB model that has been created using RStudio.

I saved the model both in .RData and .model (using `xgb.save`) types (just to increase my chances of making this work) and then uploaded both files to a folder inside DBFS (databricks).

Now, using databricks, I wanted to load the model so I can apply it to new data, but I always got the same error message. Here's the code and the error:

```
%r
# Trying to load the .RData file
load(file='/FileStore/tables/folder/xgb_model.RData')
```

Error in readChar(con, 5L, useBytes = TRUE) : cannot open the connection Error in readChar(con, 5L, useBytes = TRUE) : cannot open the connection
Error in readChar(con, 5L, useBytes = TRUE) : cannot open the connection

```
%r
# Trying to load the .model file
xgb.load("/FileStore/tables/folder/xgb_model.model")
```

Error in xgb.Booster.handle(modelfile = modelfile) : Error in xgb.Booster.handle(modelfile = modelfile) :
[23:34:59] amalgamation/../dmlc-core/src/io/local_filesys.cc:209: Check failed: allow_null:  LocalFileSystem::Open "/FileStore/tables/folder/xgb_model.model": No such file or directory

Is that even possible?

Answer (score 1):

The `FileStore` is a [special folder that is located on DBFS](https://docs.databricks.com/data/filestore.html), so to access this data, R code needs to understand DBFS.  But in your case, it can only work with the local files, that why it's failing. To make it working with files in `FileStore` as local files, you need to prepend the `/dbfs/` to the file names, like, `/dbfs/FileStore/tables/folder/xgb_model.model` (please note that it may not work on the community edition with 7.x runtime)